# Using ORDER BY and LIMIT in an SQL view

Tags: sql, view, limit

I'm trying to create a view that is limited to the last entry per id

My table structure is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `u_tbleeditlog` (
    `editID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `editType` int(1) NOT NULL,
    `editTypeID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `editedID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `editedDtm` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`editID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

And I'm trying to create a view that will only display the last entry assigned to the `Type` and `TypeID`

My view so far

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vwu_editlog AS 
SELECT u_tbleeditlog.*, CONCAT_WS(' ',u_users.user_firstname,u_users.user_lastname) AS editedEditor
FROM u_tbleeditlog
JOIN u_users ON u_users.user_id = u_tbleeditlog.editedID
ORDER BY u_tbleeditlog.editedDtm DESC LIMIT 1
```

But my problem is that this limits the entire view to just 1 result overall, and I get the message `Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.`

So say there are multiple values with `1, 1, 2017-08-16`, `1, 1, 2016-05-14` etc it will only return `1, 1, 2017-08-16`

Can anyone please tell me if what I'm trying to do is possible, and if so how? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this with the `not exists` approach to getting the last row in a series:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vwu_editlog AS 
    SELECT el.*, CONCAT_WS(' ', u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname) AS editedEditor
    FROM u_tbleeditlog el JOIN
         u_users u
         ON u.user_id = el.editedID
    WHERE not exists (select 1
                      from u_tbleeditlog el2
                      where el2.editType = el.editType and
                            el2.editTypeID = el.editTypeID and
                            el2.editedDtm > el.editedDtm
                     );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works! :). Will tick when I'm allowed

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GROUP BY and HAVING() for that. What database are you using?

It should look something like this:

```
SELECT editType, editedDtm
FROM u_tbleeditlog AS u
GROUP BY editType, editedDtm
HAVING editedDtm = (SELECT MAX(editedDtm) FROM u_tbleeditlog WHERE editType = u.editType)
ORDER BY editedDtm DESC
```